# Add tooltip to only some cells of Grid View

Tags: asp.net, gridview, tooltip

I need to add a tooltip to a `TemplateField` in a `GridView`, but only to `Row` that meets some condition. How can I achieve that?

Comment: you can call tooltip from code side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
   protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            // check for condition 
            if (e.Row.Cells[0].Text.Contains("sometext"))
            {
                 e.Row.ToolTip = "Text to be shown on mouseover of the row";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the row databound which will hit each row as it is created. Then inside use .findcontrol to get whatever control it is that you are adding a tooltip to.

Then assign the tooltip.

Wrap this in whatever condition you want to use.

If you post your current code then I may be able to help further.

Answer (score -1):

try this,
This event through you can check your all gridview rows.

gridview row event Name is =`OnRowDataBound : "GridView1_RowDataBound"`

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //Add Your Condition here
    }
}
```